# Custom font none installed - Xcode 11 beta

Tags: ios, fonts, xcode11, ios13

After installing the new beta xCode. The custom font set in an existing project does not work. When opening the storyboard file, it says as shown in image below

[image]

After clocking ok, I'm not able to choose custom font from the attribute inspector.

[image]

It was working fine with xcode 10.2. This issue occurs only on Xcode 11 beta

Comment: Is your text style `Attributed`?

Comment: @AndoniDaSilva Nope, Im using plain text only

Answer (score 3):

I've also had this issue.

I had to change the text style to attributed, pick the font, then change back to plain.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after I switched system language, and it was fixed by restarting the system and then restarting Xcode.

Comment: Happened on Xcode 12.1 as well. Restarting the Mac was the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

## 2022 Update!

You don't need to restart your system. Just perform these simple steps to solve this issue.

1. Open Spotlight (Cmd + space) and type `Font Book`
2. Drag-Drop your font into the Font Book.
3. Restart Xcode and it'll work fine.